# How do 22 and Joe Gardner communicate?

Tags: plot-explanation, soul

In the movie *Soul*, when 22 and Joe Gardner come to Earth, 22 enters body of Joe, and Joe enters the body of a cat.

When Joe, in the cat, tries to speak, other humans do not understand whereas 22 has no difficulty in understanding him.

How was it possible?

Comment: My guess is that, The writer want to show that only people that are aware of their soul and have awake soul can understand each other.